# What is the difference between automatic dereferencing and Deref coercion in Rust?

Tags: rust

As per the question, Let's say I have a following code:

```
struct Test {
 x: i32
}

fn main() {
 let test1 = Test { x: 32 }; // type inference by vscode: Test
 let test2 = &test1          // type inference by vscode: &Test
 let test3 = &test2          // type inference by vscode: &&Test

 let explicit_ref: &Test = &test3; // This should give an error but works as I haven't implemented 
                                   //Deref trait.
}
```

Did I miss anything or did I misunderstand automatic dereferencing and deref coercion?

Comment: Yes, deref coercion is taking place here, but how does that relate to the fact you haven't implemented `Deref`?

Comment: You haven't implemented `Deref` for `Test`, but there is still a blanket `Deref<Target = T>` impl for any `&T`. So an `&&T` can be coerced to an `&T`

Comment: @cameron1024 Technically, this is not using this `Deref` impl (the opposite - it uses built-in dereferencing for `&T`, it's only needed for generics).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Huh? It's exactly using (transitive) coercions through [`<&T as Deref>::deref(&self) -> &T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/deref.rs.html#80-87).

Comment: @eggyal This impl exist, but it's not what the compiler uses (unless in generic context). It's recursive itself - it refers to the builtin dereference of references.

Answer (score 1):

**Deref Coercions**

If you have a type U, and it implements Deref<Target=T>, values of &U will automatically coerce to a &T.

**Automating Referencing/Dereferencing**

Calling methods is one of the few places in Rust that has this behavior.

Here’s how it works: when you call a method with object.something(), Rust automatically adds in &, &mut, or * so object matches the signature of the method. In other words, the following are the same:

```
p1.distance(&p2);

(&p1).distance(&p2);
```

This automatic referencing behavior works because methods have a clear receiver—the type of self. Given the receiver and name of a method, Rust can figure out definitively whether the method is reading (&self), mutating (&mut self), or consuming (self).

**Sources**

You can read about Deref coercions [here](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/second-edition/ch05-03-method-syntax.html).

You can read about automatic referencing/referencing [here](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/second-edition/ch05-03-method-syntax.html).